# Mysql: How to export only indexes of all tables?

Tags: mysql

I've a local db, and other db in production server. My problem are that local db tables have more indexes than the production tables.

I can't go table by table looking what index is missing. I need export all indexes from local to production (just indexes).

**I don't want to export all database**, I want to export only table indexes like I'm doing a:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (name(10));
```

There are any way to do this? Perhaps a mysql-dump option?

I see this post: [MySql, how can I export indexes from my development database to my production database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744287/mysql-how-can-i-export-indexes-from-my-development-database-to-my-production-da) but the responses, are not a solution for me I have too many tables for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use liquibase to show you the differences of 2 Databases.

If compares field type,length and indexes and tells you whats the differenes.

see this: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html