# MYSQL Dump indexes only

Tags: mysql, indexing, dump

> I have to **backup indexes** only from a database in *MySQL*.
>   And also, I need to backup triggers only.
>   How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried something and checked official documentation? I mean lots of things are already available through google searches for mysql. Anyway maybe check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744287/mysql-how-can-i-export-indexes-from-my-development-database-to-my-production-da

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the "CREATE INDEX" statements from the information_schema by running:

```
select concat("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ",INDEX_NAME ," ON ", TABLE_NAME," (",group_concat(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX),");") from information_schema.STATISTICS where INDEX_NAME!='PRIMARY' and NON_UNIQUE=0 and TABLE_SCHEMA='my_db_name'  group by TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME order by TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME;
select concat("CREATE INDEX ",INDEX_NAME ," ON ", TABLE_NAME," (",group_concat(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX),");") from information_schema.STATISTICS where INDEX_NAME!='PRIMARY' and NON_UNIQUE=1 and TABLE_SCHEMA='my_db_name'  group by TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME order by TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME;
```

Just replace "my_db_name" with your own database name.

Comment: In my use-case I needed fully qualified table names for the indices and a DISTINCT in the GROUP_CONCAT to clean things up.  So the first query became: `select concat("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ",INDEX_NAME ," ON ", TABLE_SCHEMA, ".", TABLE_NAME," (",group_concat(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX),");") from information_schema.STATISTICS where INDEX_NAME!='PRIMARY' and NON_UNIQUE=0 and TABLE_SCHEMA <>mysql' group by TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME order by TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME;`

Answer (score 2):

It makes a LOT of sense to be able to create a DB without any indexes (other than the primary key which, more or less, dictates the physical ordering).

Migrating from a single DB to a new master/slave setup where you don't need any indexes on the master, only on the slave.

Also, if you are using Amazon's Data Migration Service (DMS), then their approach recommends having your target database without any indexes.

The approach we use is to produce a schema dump, post-process that to extract the indexes from the main schema (so now we have our initial-schema, and initial-indexes). We use repeatables for triggers, stored procedures, views, UDFs, so these are also excluded from the initial-schema.

It isn't simple. We have a lot of supporting code to help us with this.

But once done, you can test it is all working by doing another full schema export from the 2 systems and compare the results.

Good things we realised is that you name everything yourself. Indexes, foreign key constraints, etc. Relying on any default naming pattern can lead to headaches with further migrations as the creation order of things may not be identical and so the default name may not be the same.

Comment: You do need `UNIQUE` indexes to check for uniqueness at INSERT time.  You cannot swap the Primary and Replica (in a dual-master setup) without waiting for the indexes to be built.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
SELECT CONCAT("CREATE ",(CASE WHEN NON_UNIQUE = 1 THEN "" ELSE "UNIQUE " END), "INDEX ", INDEX_NAME ," ON ", TABLE_NAME," (",group_concat(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX),");") `Index Queries` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS where INDEX_NAME!='PRIMARY' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='<database_name>' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('<table1>','<table2>'.....) GROUP BY TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME;
```

Example :

```
SELECT CONCAT("CREATE ",(CASE WHEN NON_UNIQUE = 1 THEN "" ELSE "UNIQUE " END), "INDEX ", INDEX_NAME ," ON ", TABLE_NAME," (",group_concat(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX),");") `Index Queries` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS where INDEX_NAME!='PRIMARY' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='accounts' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('users','company') GROUP BY TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME;

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Index Queries                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE INDEX ix_companyId ON users (companyId);                       |
| CREATE INDEX ix_section ON users (section);                           |
| CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_userName ON users (userName);                  |
| CREATE INDEX ix_parentCompany ON company (scalparentCompany);         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

It makes zero sense to backup only the indexes.  They are not useful without the data that they reference.

Backing up just triggers: perhaps this combo will work: `mysqldump --no-data --triggers`

Comment: It makes sense. I had created some indexes on developmemt db, wanted to have them on produktion db.

I thought Mysql Workbench had an option to "export" the index to a create-statement I could paste into the production.

I ended having to do retype the indexes by hand; luckily they weren't that complicated.

Comment: @LeifNeland - Maybe we are talking about different things?  An index is a large data structure that contains the key values, together with some form of pointer to the data rows.  That's what I am talking about.  If you are talking about the one-line in the `CREATE TABLE`, please modify the question to make that clear.

Comment: I'm not going to change another guy's question ;-)
But yes; I was disappointed not being able to get the sql needed to recreate the index. I agree thet the index data by itself is not useful. It's like marking where in the lake you dropped the treasure, by making a notch in the boat.

Comment: But I have 2 same database structure both in test and production servers. I just edited the indexes both in production and test and want to compare which one is missing what. So I can't just export the indexes!?

Comment: @Tarik - If the columns are also the same, then:  `--no-data` provides `CREATE TABLE`, which includes the index definitions (and the column definitions).

Comment: It makes no sense to pretend that you know every situation. I need to figure out how to create all indexes on a copy of our database that is missing the indexes.

Comment: @nroose --no-data, plus some editing of the output, is the fastest way I can think of to get the `ADD INDEXs`.